# Can Paradoxes have 3 contradicting ideas?

Tags: meaning

I learned that a paradox has 2 contradicting ideas in my English class before but can a paradox have 3? If there is an example out there please do tell me.

Comment: The idea of opposites, contradictions and dichotomies is that they describe the relationship between _two_ things, ideas or concepts. Could three words have opposite meanings? It's like asking what the opposite of _white_ is, that is also an opposite of _black_.

Comment: @oerkelens - *Transparent*, obviously! </joke>

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question of logic or philosophy, not language.

Answer (score 1):

> can a paradox have 3?

In general English usage it's sufficient for a statement to contradict itself for it to be considered a paradox. (There are a few other definitions, though most in current use are figurative senses based on that sense of a statement that contradicts itself).

> If there is an example out there please do tell me.

That's more a question of [philosophy](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/) than English. For one thing, if something is only a paradox in English and not also in French, Russian, Greek and Chinese then it's likely a matter of something being imprecisely expressed, rather than really a paradox. (We might also question whether a paradox that breaks down into three mutual antinomies shouldn't still be considered as having a single contradiction, but that's philosophy rather than English, too).